# Add specific class depending to JSON string with Angular

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to build my first wordpress theme using AngularJS.

To do this, i'm using the WP API REST.
To create my pages, I have some flexible content (build with ACF) in order to display differents modules.
When I create modules in a single post ,I have this JSON output :

[IMAGE OF ACF JSON OUTPUT FROM WP REST API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG6kX.png)

```
"modules": [{
    acf_fc_layout": "module_photo_texte",
    "disposition": "text-photo",
    "photo": {},
    "texte": "",
    "": null,
    "largeur_gauche": "50",
    "largeur_droite": "50"
    },
    {
    "acf_fc_layout": "module_titre",
    "titre": "Test de titre"
    },
    ...
]
```

From this JSON I would like to be able to add class to my module's div according to the **acf_fc_layout** and the **disposition** fields (if it exists)

Because i'm new to Angular,
I'm trying that way, but I'm definitely sure that it's not the right way.

```
<div ng-repeat="modules in project.acf.modules">
    <section ng-if="modules.acf_fc_layout === 'module_photo_texte' && modules.disposition === 'text-photo'" ng-class="'text-photo photo-text-module'">
    </section>
    <section ng-if="modules.acf_fc_layout === 'module_photo_texte' && modules.disposition === 'photo-text'" ng-class="'photo-text photo-text-module'">
    </section>
    <section ng-if="modules.acf_fc_layout === 'module_titre'" ng-class="title-module">
    </section>
</div>
```

I think that the ng-repeat would be in my `<section>` but in this case, I have no idea on How I can display the good classes in my ng-class attributes. Maybe I have to do this in the Controller ?

Thanks for help guys

Damien

Comment: use ng-class to add dynamic class, read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 0):

So, in your case, you need to add conditions in your ng-class:

```
<any ng-class="{'class1': condition1, 'class2': condition2}"></any>
```

So your html could be like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="modules in project.acf.modules">
    <section ng-class="{'title-module': modules.acf_fc_layout === 'module_titre',
                        'photo-text photo-text-module': modules.acf_fc_layout === 'module_photo_texte' && modules.disposition === 'photo-text',
                        'text-photo photo-text-module':  modules.acf_fc_layout === 'module_photo_texte' && modules.disposition === 'text-photo' }"></section>
    </section>
</div>
```

EDIT:

if you would like just to add the dynamic values of the attributes, it could be like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="modules in project.acf.modules">
    <section class="{{modules.acf_fc_layout}} {{modules.disposition}}"></section>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, because I have 9 modules, but this solution can be ok. But I have different string to output according to the layout type. For exemple "texte" for module_photo_texte or "titre" for module_titre. So I have to put some ng-if inside this section ?

Comment: if you would like just to add the value of the modules.acf_fc_layout and modules.disposition, you could add by this: `<section class="{{modules.acf_fc_layout}} {{modules.disposition}}"></section>`